# Unusual Error Using OpenGL Buffers with Cuda interop on MS Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I was writing a very simple piece of code given in the cuda by example book which is the cuda openGL interop creating graphics. The program is getting build successfully but when I am running the program the windows shows :
The application was unable to start correctly. 
Click OK to close the application.
I don't know why it happening cause I have few sample cuda programs which are running successfully as well as the opengl sample programs. I even run the sample cuda openGL interop program from the NVidia Sample program which is running successfully. I should mention here that I have included all the lib files in the additional libraries as well as the included files in the additional include directories. I believe that this is happening because of the pixel buffers that I am using for the interop cause normal openGL and cuda program are running fine. I should also mention that visual studio intellisense is showing the buffers API (like glGenBuffers,etc.) when I am trying to include those in the program but after declaring in the program it is showing that the identifier is undefined with a red line underneath it. But this thing is not happening in the NVidia sample OpenGL code.

I am pasting the code below :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glaux.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cutil.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#define     DIM    512

GLuint  bufferObj;
cudaGraphicsResource *resource;

// based on ripple code, but uses uchar4 which is the type of data
// graphic inter op uses. see screenshot - basic2.png
__global__ void kernel( uchar4 *ptr ) {
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    // now calculate the value at that position
    float fx = x/(float)DIM - 0.5f;
    float fy = y/(float)DIM - 0.5f;
    unsigned char   green = 128 + 127 *
        sin( abs(fx*100) - abs(fy*100) );

    // accessing uchar4 vs unsigned char*
    ptr[offset].x = 0;
    ptr[offset].y = green;
    ptr[offset].z = 0;
    ptr[offset].w = 255;
}

static void key_func( unsigned char key, int x, int y ) {
    switch (key) {
    case 27:
        // clean up OpenGL and CUDA
         cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource( resource );
        glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0 );
        glDeleteBuffers( 1, &bufferObj );
        exit(0);
    }
}

static void draw_func( void ) {

    glDrawPixels( DIM, DIM, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    cudaDeviceProp  prop;
    int dev;

    memset( &prop, 0, sizeof( cudaDeviceProp ) );
    prop.major = 1;
    prop.minor = 0;
     cudaChooseDevice( &dev, &prop );
    cudaGLSetGLDevice( dev ) ;
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( DIM, DIM );
    glutCreateWindow( "bitmap" );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &bufferObj );
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferObj );
    glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, DIM * DIM * 4,NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer( &resource, 
        bufferObj, 
        cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone ) ;

    // do work with the memory dst being on the GPU, gotten via mapping
     cudaGraphicsMapResources( 1, &resource, NULL ) ;
    uchar4* devPtr;
    size_t  size;
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer( (void**)&devPtr, 
        &size, 
        resource) ;

    dim3    grids(DIM/16,DIM/16);
    dim3    threads(16,16);
    kernel<<<grids,threads>>>( devPtr );
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources( 1, &resource, NULL ) ;

    glutKeyboardFunc( key_func );
    glutDisplayFunc( draw_func );
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Please debug a bit further on your own before you post a lot of code. You can narrow it down quite a bit just by using the debugger: compile a debug configuration.  Put a breakpoint on the first line of main().  Run in the debugger, and step until you see where it fails.

Comment: on my machine with GTX580 graphics card under Linux, it works with no problems. Cool graph by the way ))

Comment: maybe you should check whether PBO is supported on your system (if you haven't done this already) ie. glGetString(GL_EXTENSION) check for GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object

Comment: Hi!
I started to debug my code. I put the breakpoints but when I am starting to debug then it is straight showing the same message and I am not able to debug the code.So the problem still persists after trying different things.

Comment: @asm : I did the glGetString(GL_EXTENSION) and printed it but it is returning  NULL.

Comment: nope, you should try glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) with 'S' at the end, my mistake

Comment: Thanks for your reply.After struggling a lot in the windows side I just gave up hope on windows portion and jumped onto linux portion. First I installed the freeglut and then I installed the toolkit and the sdk. But when I am executing 'make' command in the NVidia Cuda SDK then it is not able to compile the particle example and exiting with error. From the error type it seems that it could be an openGL problem.I tried to write simple openGL code.While trying to compile it then it is showing error. The first error is:
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open //usr/lib/libGL.so: No such file or directory

Comment: @asm The rest of the errors are like this
usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cctUuPse.o: in function draw:openGL_test.c(.text+0x1b): error: undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cctUuPse.o: in function draw:openGL_test.c(.text+0x25): error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cctUuPse.o: in function draw:openGL_test.c(.text+0x2a): error: undefined reference to 'glFlush'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
When I was compiling particle code then at that point it also showed
 '/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open //usr/lib/libGL.so: No such file or directory ' followed by others.

Comment: first you can check that /usr/lib/libGL.so indeed exists on your system. Are you compiling for 32 or 64-bits ? It might be that required libraries are located somewhere else: check also /usr/lib64/ or /usr/lib32/ depending on your system defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to `glewInit()` before `glGenBuffers()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @samsamX: well given that it crashes if you don't initialise GLEW and doesn't crash if you do initialise GLEW, and given that the question is asking for help because the code crashes, I'd argue that it does answer the question! But I could have been more verbose, that's true!

Comment: I am sorry for my late reply but I just saw the answers and suggestions. I included the glewInit() in my code but it is still giving the same error. As harrism mentioned, I would try to debug the code later today and would try to be more specific. But in the mean time if you have more suggestions then please let me know. I want to run this code as soon as possible. Thanking you for all your help.